# Azure Devops using product backlogitems instead of tasks in a sprint

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

Can I change a setting somewhere in Azure DevOps so I can drag and drop Product Backlog Items instead of tasks in a sprint? For most of our items we don't need to create a task .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the context of drag-and-drop of the tasks, where do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and drop Product Backlog Items in a sprint from **Backlog** page instead of Taskboard page. In **Backlo**g page, you could drag and drop PBI to reorder them:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?